# Path to my media file won't work in django project

Tags: javascript, django, path

I've tried to put my site that I've designed into django, and I've encountered some problemes with paths to my media file in css and javascript but now my css paths work but my javascripts file don't.
Thanks in advance for any help provided!

I've tried to change my STATIC_URL and all but it didn't work. it seems like django is changing my path for no reason.

WORKING:
How I wrote my Path into css (works.css in my project)

```
@font-face { font-family: gameboy; src: url('media/font/gameboy.ttf'); }
background-image: url('media/gif/drive3.gif');
```

NOT WORKING:
How I wrote my Path into javascript (works.js in my project)

```
var pic1 = 'media/picture/travis.jpg';
var pic2 = 'media/picture/snoop.jpg';
var pic3 = 'media/gif/vash.gif';
var pic4 = 'media/picture/snoop.jpg';
```

The http response:

```
[07/Aug/2019 10:23:51] "GET /works/media/picture/snoop.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3066
```

My Settings file:

```
Django settings for Music project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 't867#%uk)99t*28%uxk5mbj5c7)&7*x9^r&g&12*-fdja6jovl'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Musicapp.apps.MusicappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Music.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Music.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Thanks again!
Thewizy

Comment: If that `media` directory is directly under the root, try using absolute paths starting with `/` everywhere, like `/media/gif/....`

Comment: I already tried that and it's not even changing the final path in the http response :/

Comment: Please help me :(

Comment: try it like /Musicapp/static/media/gif/drive3.gif. Edit : Are all these static files exclusively for that single app? If not, place the static directory directly under root folder and minimise the path